# Apache Nifi: use OAuth 2.0 to Access Google Analytics APIs

Tags: rest, oauth, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, apache-nifi

I try to use OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs (Google Analytics API v4) in Apache Nifi.
I using Service Account basing on this document: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

There is one specific moment if using OAuth 2.0 for Service Account (Google API):
These service-account scenarios require creating and cryptographically signing JSON Web Tokens (JWTs). 
The best example of OAuth access will be using NiFi + JWT:

1. Create a JWT
2. Request an access token from the Google OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server
3. Handle the JSON response from Authorization Server

Point 1 (about JWT) is most interesting.

Are there any examples of already implemented flows exactly For Google Analytics?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any specifically for Google Analytics, but there are plenty of examples of OAuth 1.0/2.0 access using Apache NiFi. In general, you will use the `InvokeHTTP` processor to perform `GET`/`POST`/etc. HTTP operations against the remote endpoint.

Without specifying an issue you are encountering, I would suggest you read these articles:

- [HCC: Using GetHTTP for Salesforce Integration with OAuth2.0 authentication parameter](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/46800/using-gethttp-for-salesforce-integration-with-oaut.html)
- [OAuth 1.0A with Apache NiFi (Twitter API example)](https://pierrevillard.com/2016/04/12/oauth-1-0a-with-apache-nifi-twitter-api-example/)
- [How to set Twitter OAuth attributes to InvokeHttp processor for fetching twitter user profiles](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/26999/how-to-set-twitter-oauth-attributes-to-invokehttp.html)
- [NiFi OAuth 2.0 Template](https://gist.github.com/pvillard31/c2926fdcff57b017a771d2d1acdb5cba)
- [Google Vision & Apache NiFi - Making Advanced Computer Vision Feasible](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/56484/google-vision-apache-nifi-making-advanced-computer.html)

Comment: Thank you, Andy! 
Accordingly to your remark about specifics I updated the question.
There is one specific moment if using OAuth 2.0 for Service Account (Google API):
These service-account scenarios require creating and cryptographically signing JSON Web Tokens (JWTs). 
The best example of OAuth access will be using NiFi + JWT

Comment: @Bo.: I am looking for exactly this. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @simran-kaur, basically I not figured out NiFi + JWT, but my solution is custom processor which includes google-api-client and google-api-services-analyticsreporting libarries. So by that libraries I create GoogleCredential object and AnalyticsReporting client object. Then I use AnalyticsReporting client object for querying GA Report API v4.

Comment: ALright. Are these processors available and open source? Do you mind sharing the link?

Comment: There is now a [PR for an OAuth 2.0 controller service](https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/2085) which may be interesting to you.

Comment: @simran-kaur, I programmed the processor myself. But to get GoogleCredential and AnalyticsReporting client objects I added to project following libraries: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/ https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/analyticsreporting/v4

Comment: Did anyone find out how to solve this w/o a custom processor?

Comment: I am reviewing a [PR which would provide this as a controller service](https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/2085).